# Text within larger Text - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the Square brackets to encompass the text, instead of going to either side. I have looked for a solution but not found one, hence coming here. I have attempted on a previous occasion to do this with tables and not succeeded. Any attempts would be greatly helpful! :D

Current:
[image: Current outcome]
Desired:
[image: Desired outcome]
HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <h2>[</h2>
            <h1>BLOG TITLE HERE</h1>
            <h2>]</h2>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Music for journeys</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Cake is good</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:424242;
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:15;
    color:FFF;
}

.title{
    width:100;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
}

h1{
    font-size:40;
}

h2{
    font-size:120;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color:FFF;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:0;
    border-top-width:2;
    border-color:1C1C1C;    
}
```

Comment: An Image of what this is **supposed** to look like would help....I assume the one you've provided isn't it?

Comment: And note that heading elements should not be used for styling purposes, unless the content has a special meaning.

Comment: @HashemQolami What should be used

Comment: I'd go with `<span>` — as it is a generic inline-level container with no special meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS square brackets.

Adapted from this [**Article**](http://jaspreetchahal.org/pure-css-square-brackets/)

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/brg8p1rx/3/)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 2px solid #666;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -5px;
}
h1:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2px solid #666;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>BLOG TITLE HERE</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set their display to `inline-block`.

```
.title h2,
.title h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Now, play with their font sizes and margin to achieve the desired effect.

```
.title h2 {
    font-size: 110px;
    margin: -10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.title h1 {
    max-width: 90px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqqoL7t8/3/), with some further tweaks.

Comment: How would I do that with the multiple lines?

Comment: Use `max-width`. Updated answer.

Comment: Still getting the same result as before when using your code :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` as well.

**CSS**

```
.title h1 {
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:Arial;
    position:relative;
}

.title h1:before {
    content: "[ ";
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
}

.title h1:after {
    content: " ]";
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/brg8p1rx/)

EDIT: Based on your new image of what it should look like, using `inline-block` in the solution above would probably be best.

**CSS for desired effect, using absolute positioning**

```
.title {
    text-align:center;
}
.title h1 {
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:Arial;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.title h1:before {
    content: "[ ";
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:-30px;
    font-size:80px;
}

.title h1:after {
    content: " ]";
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-30px;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean?

Comment: See the "Desired" image he posted.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to achieve the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/brg8p1rx/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D. Yeah, he posted that after my answer. And I even edited my answer. I've also added what he would want using `pseudo elements`

Comment: See my answer which, I admit. is copied from the article I think this is what he is after..It's responsive and font size independent.(ish)